# adding span to a text in div using jQuery

Tags: jquery

I have something like this :

```
 <div class="SomeClass"> 
 <label> something </label>
 14 
 </div>
  <div class="SomeClass"> 
 <label> something </label>
 8
 </div>
```

Using jQuery, I want to include each number in a span so I can style it independent of the whole div.

So I want it to become:

```
 <div class="SomeClass"> 
 <label> something </label>
 <span> 14 </span>
 </div>
  <div class="SomeClass"> 
 <label> something </label>
 <span> 8 </span>
 </div>
```

Having spent a lot of time searching, I tried this and I didn't think it's useful to share:

```
  $(" [class='SomeClass'] ").each(function() {
    $(this).clone().children().remove().end().text().append('<span>');
    $(this).clone().children().remove().end().text().prepend('</span>');
  });
```

I am a newbie with jQuery and still learning so please be more considerate before down-voting me.

Comment: Show us what you have tried first

Comment: Edited. @Rob Kwasowski thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can clone `label` element to a temporary variable, then removing it and getting the text inside `SomeClass` element. Like this:

```js
$('.SomeClass').each(function () {
  var $self = $(this);
  
  var label = $self.find('label');
  
  var _label = label.clone();
  
  label.remove();
  
  var text = $self.text().trim();
  
  $self.html(_label).append(`<span>${text}</span>`);
});

$('.SomeClass').each(function () {
  console.log(this.outerHTML);
})
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div class="SomeClass"> 
 <label> something </label>
 14 
 </div>
  <div class="SomeClass"> 
 <label> something </label>
 8
 </div>
```